# Filling a data frame using matrix data

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, igraph

I have a large symmetric matrix filled with weights:

```
          AT      BE     CH     CZ
AT    0       0.00276 0.148  0.109
BE    0.00276 0       0.145  0.112
CH    0.148   0.145   0      0.257
CZ    0.109   0.112   0.257  0
```

I need to create a data frame that lists the links between all elements (except for the same, e.g. AT and AT, BE and BE etc.) and corresponding weights. In other words, I don't know how to fill my data frame with data from the matrix. The data frame should look somewhat similar to

```
df<-data.frame(from = c("AT", "BE", "CH", "CZ"), to= c("BE", "CH", "CZ", "AT"),
weight=c(0.003,0.145,0.257,0.109))
```

I need this type of data frame to visualize it further with **igraph** , as advised here [Visualizing data on geographic map with networks (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49454687/visualizing-data-on-geographic-map-with-networks-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Matrix** holding weights:

```
mtx <- matrix( 
   c(0,0.00276,0.148,0.109,0.00276,0,0.145,0.112,0.148,0.145,0,0.257,0.109,0.112,0.257,0),  
   nrow=4, 
   ncol=4) 
rownames(mtx) <- c('AT','BE','CH','CZ')
colnames(mtx) <- c('AT','BE','CH','CZ')
```

[image]

**Function** for converting weights matrix to weights frame:

```
mtx_to_igraph_frame <- function(mtx) {
    combs <- expand.grid(rownames(mtx), colnames(mtx))
    combs <- subset(combs, Var1 != Var2)
    combs <- t(apply(combs, 1, sort))
    combs <- combs[!duplicated(combs),]
    extract_vals <- NULL
    for(i in 1:nrow(combs)) { extract_vals[i] <- mtx[combs[i,1],combs[i,2]] }
    combs <- data.frame(combs)
    combs$weight <- extract_vals
    names(combs) <- c('from', 'to', 'weight')
    row.names(combs) <- NULL
    return(combs)
    }
```

**Usage**:

```
mtx_to_igraph_frame(mtx)
```

**Result**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If we convert the matrix to a data frame, I believe we could do something like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(from, weight_index) %>% 
  group_by(from) %>% 
  mutate(weight = lead(weight_index, default = weight_index[1])) %>% 
  filter(weight_index == 0) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(to = lead(from, default = from[1])) %>% 
  select(from, to, weight)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 3
>   from  to     weight
>   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
> 1 AT    BE    0.00276
> 2 BE    CH    0.145  
> 3 CH    CZ    0.257  
> 4 CZ    AT    0.109
> ```

1. We take the data frame and `gather` it to long format. This creates the variables `from` and `weight_index`.
2. Then we group by `from` (i.e. `AT`, `BE`, `CH`, `CZ`).
3. Create `weight` var which leads `weight_index` and recycles the values, replacing `NA` values (resulting from the group `lead`) with the first `weight_index` value of each group.
4. `filter` rows where `weight_index == 0`.
5. `ungroup`
6. Create `to` var which leads `from` and recycles the values, replacing the `NA` value with the first `from` value (i.e. give row 4 of var `to` value `AT`).
7. `select` the columns we want and in the desired order.

---

Data:

```
Lines <- "AT      BE     CH     CZ
          AT    0       0.00276 0.148  0.109
          BE    0.00276 0       0.145  0.112
          CH    0.148   0.145   0      0.257
          CZ    0.109   0.112   0.257  0"

df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will do what you want. Note the difference of the values of `weight` at the end.

First, the input data.

```
mat <-
structure(c(0, 0.00276, 0.148, 0.109, 0.00276, 0, 0.145, 0.112, 
0.148, 0.145, 0, 0.257, 0.109, 0.112, 0.257, 0), .Dim = c(4L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(c("AT", "BE", "CH", "CZ"), c("AT", "BE", 
"CH", "CZ")))
```

Now, the code.

```
mat2 <- cbind(mat[, -1], mat[, 1])
colnames(mat2)[ncol(mat2)] <- colnames(mat)[1]
mat2

df2 <- data.frame(from = rownames(mat2), to = colnames(mat2), weight = diag(mat2))

df<-data.frame(from = c("AT", "BE", "CH", "CZ"), to= c("BE", "CH", "CZ", "AT"),
weight=c(0.003,0.145,0.257,0.109))

all.equal(df, df2)
#[1] "Component “weight”: Mean relative difference: 0.08"
```

This "error" is due to round-off errors, in your sample output you, for instance, round `0.00276` to `0.003`.